# Expression can be simplified. Checkstyle

Tags: java, if-statement, checkstyle

How can I simplify this? The variable `fuel` is a `boolean` from a parent class named `Vehicle`. The `useTax()` method is an abstract method from the same `Vehicle` class.

When I go about running checkstyle, it comes up with the string "Expression can be simplified." and highlights `if (fuel == true)`.

```
public double useTax() {
    double tax;
    if (fuel == true) { // <-- why?
        tax = value * ALTERNATIVE_FUEL_TAX_RATE;
    }
    else {
        tax = value * TAX_RATE;
    }
    if (value > LUXURY_THRESHOLD) {
        tax += value * LUXURY_TAX_RATE;
    }
    return tax;
}
```

Comment: remove the `== true`. When checking booleans, you could use `if(bool)` to check if its true, and `if(!bool)` to check if its false

Answer (score 7):

I think it's telling you that

```
if (fuel == true)
```

can be written more concisely as

```
if (fuel)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what it means is instead of "if(fuel == true)", you can simplify it too "if(fuel)"

Answer (score 2):

```
if (fuel == true)
```

Here your code has unnecessary `boolean` redundancy.

You can just use

```
if (fuel)
```